# How to send JSONArray with JsonObjectRequest using volley

Tags: android, android-volley

We can send JSONObject with JsonObjectRequest using volley. How can we send JSONArray with JsonObjectRequest?

Comment: can you give example what you want to send ?

Comment: so i can give demo

Comment: Yaa Sure. Just give me a min.

Comment: Please see my Answer which is below. I was not able to post my code as comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **JsonArrayRequest** for **JSONArray** parameter.

Comment: but this Web API is returning JSONObject and it needs JSONArray as a parameter.

Comment: then put jsonarray in jsonobject

Comment: API can accept only JSONArray then how can i send JSONObject to Web API?

Comment: change return type from api side

Comment: Why can i not request for JSONObject and send JSONArray?

Comment: a json by default starts with an object i.e everything has to be inside these curly braces { } even an array. Validate the json which you are sending to the api using this site http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks Akash. I have done the same thing. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

` JSONArray jsonArray1 = new JSONArray();

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.POST, url, jsonArray1, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject score_response) {
                    // the response is already constructed as a JSONObject!

                    Log.e(TAG, score_response.toString());

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);`
```

jsonArray1 is not compatible here. it's showing error. If i am putting JSONObject here then it's working fine.